# MVC4 C# problemas al llamar Action desde Controller

Tags: c#, mvc, jqgrid

tengo un index.cshtml que contiene una grilla *JqGrid*, la cual se llena con un metodo del controller y anda correctamente.
(invoca al metodo desde el cliente y se llenan todos sus campos)

Luego tengo una función **_editRow** que se ejecuta cuando se da doble click a algún registro de la grilla y esta función también llama a un metido que solo traería los detalles de este registro, pero no lo hace.
intente muchas cosas, pero la función **_editRow** nunca llega a invocar al método del controlador. ni siquiera accede a la primer linea de él.

a continuación dejo los métodos y llamadas en cuestión.

Index.csHTML

```
$(document).ready(InicialProductor);
$.jgrid.gridUnload("#tblJQGrid");//FUnciona Perfecto

function Inicial(filter) {
    $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid({
        mtype: 'POST',
        url: '/Productor/ListaInicial', //Llamada al metodo para llenar grilla

        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Col01', 'Col02', 'Col03', 'Col04', ],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Col01', index: 'Col01', width: 255, stype: 'text'},
            { name: 'Col02', index: 'Col02', width: 90, align: "center" },
            { name: 'Col03', index: 'Col03', width: 150, align: "center" },
            { name: 'Col04', index: 'Col04', width: 80, align: "center" },

        ],
        emptyrecords: 'No existen movimientos vigentes!',
        rowNum: 10000,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'Desc',
        caption: "Produccion",
        scrollOffset: 0,
        height: 'auto',
        loadonce: true,
        multiselect: false,
        postData: {
            desc: filter
        },
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            var countRows = $("#tblJQGrid").getRowData().length;
            if (countRows === 0) {
                NoFaund();
            }
        },
        ondblClickRow: function () {
            detailRow();// esto se ejecutará al hacer doble click sobre un registro

        }
    });
```

Método Inicial()//para llenar la grilla

```
public ActionResult ListaInicial(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string desc = "")
    {               
        //algo de logica
        var data = new
        {
            rows = from c in list
                   select new
                   {
                       cell = new string[]
                        {
                            c.Col01,
                            c.Col02,
                            c.Col03,
                            c.Col04
                        }
                   }
        };
        return Json(data);
    }
```

Index.csHTML //aca comenza el problema

```
function detailRow() {
    var idRow = $('#tblJQGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    //Obtengo el numero del campo 01 para ir a buscar el detalle
    var data = $('#tblJQGrid'),
        selRowId = data.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
        celValue = data.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Col01');

         $.MDmessage({
            messageType: "popup",
            name: "popup_detailRow",
            btnok: true,
            title: "Detalles de: " + celValue,
            width: 50,
            mtype: 'POST',
            content: 'Url.Action("_DetailRowsPza")'?id=' +celValue
        });
}
```

Metodo para detalle

```
 public ActionResult _DetailRowsPza(int id)
    {          
     //algo de lógica por acá
        var data = new
            {
               ///otro por poco de lógica por acá también
            };
            return PartialView("_detail", data);
        }
```